# LDAP Virtual appliance

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

Is there any virtual appliance that has LDAP installed, if possible based on linux?
I want to test LDAP and would like to get it installed and configured in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking at it as an Active Directory alternative may I suggest taking a look at http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller, it has LDAP built in but also has all the Samba software required to run as a stand-alone domain controller.

Comment: Are you sure it has LDAP built in? I can't see any info on the link you provided. I imported it into VBox but can't see LDAP server running.

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/385
- http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/595133
- http://www.instantbox.net/virtual-appliance/openldap-directory-server-instantbox